# Mapbox crash when rapidly switching between fragments

Tags: android, kotlin, fatal-error, mapbox-android

When rapidly switching between my map-fragment and any other fragment "Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV)" occurs and the app crashes. I have read that this error is related to a library function issue and I am guessing it has something to do with the function in my onConnected() method, hence the Log message. Any help on how to resolve the issue is appreciated, thank you.

```
Relevant code:
@SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
override fun onStart() {
    val settings = context?.getSharedPreferences(preferencesFile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    downloadDate = settings?.getString("lD", "").toString()
    if (downloadDate != currentDate){
        //some stuff that is not being executed, not relevant for the error
    }
    super.onStart()
    if(PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this.context)){
        locationEngine?.requestLocationUpdates()
        locationLayerPlugin?.onStart()
    }
    mapView.onStart()
}
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    mapView.onResume()
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    mapView.onPause()
}
override fun onStop() {
    val settings = context?.getSharedPreferences(preferencesFile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val editor = settings?.edit()
    editor?.putString("lD", downloadDate)
    editor?.apply()
    locationEngine?.removeLocationUpdates()
    locationLayerPlugin?.onStop()
    super.onStop()
    mapView.onStop()
}
override fun onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory()
    mapView.onLowMemory()
}
override fun onDestroy() {
    locationEngine?.deactivate()
    val settings = context?.getSharedPreferences(preferencesFile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val editor = settings?.edit()
    editor?.putString("shil", shilview.text.toString())
    editor?.putString("dolr", dolrview.text.toString())
    editor?.putString("quid", quidview.text.toString())
    editor?.putString("peny", shilview.text.toString())
    editor?.apply()
    super.onDestroy()
    mapView.onDestroy()
}
override fun onDestroyView() {
    mapView.onDestroy()
    super.onDestroyView()
}

override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    mapView.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
}
@SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
override fun onConnected() {
    Log.d(t, "[onConnected] requesting location updates")
    locationEngine?.requestLocationUpdates()
}

override fun onExplanationNeeded(permissionsToExplain: MutableList<String>?) {
    Log.d(t, "Permissions: $permissionsToExplain")
}

override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location?) {
    location?.let{
        originLocation = location
        setCameraPosition(location)
    }
}

override fun onPermissionResult(granted: Boolean) {
    Log.d(t, "[onPermissionResult] granted == $granted")
    if(granted){
        enableLocation()
    }else{
        Toast.makeText(context, "Let me know where you are. Hide and seek is not my game.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
}

override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    permissionsManager.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
}
private fun enableLocation(){
    if (PermissionsManager.areLocationPermissionsGranted(this.context)){
        Log.d(t, "Permissions granted")
        initLocationEngine()
        initLocationLayer()
    }else{
        Log.d(t, "Permissions denied")
        permissionsManager = PermissionsManager(this)
        permissionsManager.requestLocationPermissions(this.activity)
    }
}

private fun setCameraPosition(location: Location){
    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(LatLng(location.latitude, location.longitude)))
}

@SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
private fun initLocationEngine(){
    locationEngine = LocationEngineProvider(this.context).obtainBestLocationEngineAvailable()
    locationEngine?.apply {
        interval = 5000
        fastestInterval = 1000
        priority = LocationEnginePriority.HIGH_ACCURACY
        activate()
    }
    val lastLocation = locationEngine?.lastLocation
    if(lastLocation != null){
        originLocation = lastLocation
        setCameraPosition(lastLocation)
    }else{
        locationEngine?.addLocationEngineListener(this)
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("MissingPermission")
private fun initLocationLayer(){
    locationLayerPlugin = LocationLayerPlugin(mapView, map, locationEngine)
    locationLayerPlugin?.apply{
        setLocationLayerEnabled(true)
        cameraMode = CameraMode.TRACKING
        renderMode = RenderMode.NORMAL
    }
}



    Debugger:
    D/FragmentMap: Permissions granted
    D/FragmentMap: [onConnected] requesting location updates
    V/AudioManager: playSoundEffect   effectType: 0
    W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x711ce13010 disconnect failed
    D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.23, mControlPoint1y = 0.06, mControlPoint2x = 0.09, mControlPoint2y = 0.97
    D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.6, mControlPoint1y = 0.9, mControlPoint2x = 0.8, mControlPoint2y = 1.0
    D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.23, mControlPoint1y = 0.06, mControlPoint2x = 0.09, mControlPoint2y = 0.97
    D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.6, mControlPoint1y = 0.9, mControlPoint2x = 0.8, mControlPoint2y = 1.0
    V/AudioManager: playSoundEffect   effectType: 0
    I/zygote64: Do full code cache collection, code=1007KB, data=661KB
    I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=1003KB, data=590KB
    V/Mbgl-ConnectivityReceiver: Connected: true
    I/Mbgl-EGLConfigChooser: In emulator: false
    D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
    D/FragmentMap: Permissions granted
    D/FragmentMap: [onConnected] requesting location updates
    V/AudioManager: playSoundEffect   effectType: 0
    W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x711ce13010 disconnect failed
    D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.23, mControlPoint1y = 0.06, mControlPoint2x = 0.09, mControlPoint2y = 0.97
    D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.6, mControlPoint1y = 0.9, mControlPoint2x = 0.8, mControlPoint2y = 1.0
    D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.23, mControlPoint1y = 0.06, mControlPoint2x = 0.09, mControlPoint2y = 0.97
    D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.6, mControlPoint1y = 0.9, mControlPoint2x = 0.8, mControlPoint2y = 1.0
    V/AudioManager: playSoundEffect   effectType: 0
    V/Mbgl-ConnectivityReceiver: Connected: true
    I/Mbgl-EGLConfigChooser: In emulator: false
    D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, egl_color_buffer_format *, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
    D/FragmentMap: Permissions granted
    V/AudioManager: playSoundEffect   effectType: 0
    I/zygote64: Do partial code cache collection, code=1003KB, data=614KB
    I/zygote64: After code cache collection, code=1003KB, data=614KB
    I/zygote64: Increasing code cache capacity to 3MB
    W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x711ce13010 disconnect failed
    D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.23, mControlPoint1y = 0.06, mControlPoint2x = 0.09, mControlPoint2y = 0.97
    D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.6, mControlPoint1y = 0.9, mControlPoint2x = 0.8, mControlPoint2y = 1.0
    CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.23, mControlPoint1y = 0.06, mControlPoint2x = 0.09, mControlPoint2y = 0.97
    D/CubicBezierInterpolator: CubicBezierInterpolator  mControlPoint1x = 0.6, mControlPoint1y = 0.9, mControlPoint2x = 0.8, mControlPoint2y = 1.0
    D/FragmentMap: [onConnected] requesting location updates
    V/AudioManager: playSoundEffect   effectType: 0
    A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x30 in tid 7693 (.frederik.coinz)
    Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

Comment: I would suggest reporting this issue to the library developers.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using `Mapbox` in a `Fragment`.

Keep `mapView.onDestroy()` below super call @ `onDestroyView()` method of `Fragment` and take `mapView.onDestroy()` out of `Fragment's` `onDestroy()` method. As per [this issue on github](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/11153).

Also read [how it hould be used in fragment](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/overview/).

Your method will look like this.

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    locationEngine?.deactivate()
    val settings = context?.getSharedPreferences(preferencesFile, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val editor = settings?.edit()
    editor?.putString("shil", shilview.text.toString())
    editor?.putString("dolr", dolrview.text.toString())
    editor?.putString("quid", quidview.text.toString())
    editor?.putString("peny", shilview.text.toString())
    editor?.apply()
    super.onDestroy()
    //mapView.onDestroy() not required here for Fragment
}
 override fun onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView()
    mapView.onDestroy() //after super call

}
```